# Посчитать процент встречаемости не нулевых элементов для каждого месяца

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть Дата фрэйм 1 столбец это даты к примеру (от 13:01:2018 - 07:04:2018), второй столбец числа 0 и 1. Нужно для каждого месяца рассчитать процент встречаемости не нулевых значений(к примеру в 1 месяце процент содержания будет равен 27%, во втором 19% и т.д) и чтобы получилась таблица вида:

```
date           percent
13:01:2018     0.27
14:01:2018     0.27
...            ...
...            ...
01:02:2018     0.19
...            ...
07:04:2018     0.35
```

Comment: Под месяцем вы понимаете просто месяц или год и месяц? Т.е. в общем случае у вас должно получиться 12 значений или больше?

Comment: @MaxU Рассчитываться будет только для нескольких месяцев, года впринцепи не нужны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

Создаем тестовый DataFrame:

```
In [99]: dates = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2019-06-01", freq="3D")

In [100]: df = (pd.DataFrame({
                   "date":dates, 
                   "val":np.random.choice([0,1], len(dates), p=[0.6, 0.4])})
                  .sample(frac=1)
                  .reset_index(drop=True))

In [101]: df
Out[101]:
          date  val
0   2019-01-26    0
1   2018-08-08    0
2   2018-11-21    0
3   2018-07-03    0
4   2018-12-06    1
5   2018-11-09    0
6   2019-01-17    0
..         ...  ...
166 2019-02-28    1
167 2019-02-07    1
168 2018-10-28    1
169 2019-01-29    0
170 2019-05-11    0
171 2019-05-05    0
172 2018-09-01    1

[173 rows x 2 columns]
```

решение:

```
df["pct"] = df.groupby(df["date"].dt.month)["val"].transform("mean")
```

результат:

```
In [103]: df
Out[103]:
          date  val       pct
0   2019-01-26    0  0.285714
1   2018-08-08    0  0.400000
2   2018-11-21    0  0.400000
3   2018-07-03    0  0.300000
4   2018-12-06    1  0.500000
5   2018-11-09    0  0.400000
6   2019-01-17    0  0.285714
..         ...  ...       ...
166 2019-02-28    1  0.473684
167 2019-02-07    1  0.473684
168 2018-10-28    1  0.727273
169 2019-01-29    0  0.285714
170 2019-05-11    0  0.285714
171 2019-05-05    0  0.285714
172 2018-09-01    1  0.500000

[173 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: С телефона набирали ответ? Кавычки уж больно странные получились :)

Comment: @gil9red, да, iPhone не позволяет ввести обычные кавычки. Спасибо за исправление! :)

Comment: @MaxU Выдаёт ошибку, "Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas", через цикл проверил тип данных столбца с датами <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> я, так понял нужно переконвертировать тип данных столбца с датами?

Comment: @percent, т.е. у вас тип данных `datetime64` реально отображается с двоеточиями - `13:01:2018`?? Никогда раньше с таким не встречался...

Comment: @MaxU почему, нет. В консоли отображается через "-"